# react native expo not importing function from NX monorepo packages

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I am setting up a NX monorepo containing a package is-even and i have a front end expo react native app calling the function from this package. However, it gives me the error below.

```
Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `is-even` from file `/Users/user/project/eclipse-frontend/mobile-app/src/app/App.tsx`, the package `/Users/user/project/eclipse-frontend/packages/is-even/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/user/project/eclipse-frontend/packages/is-even/dist/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * /Users/user/project/eclipse-frontend/packages/is-even/dist/index.js(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
  * /Users/user/project/eclipse-frontend/packages/is-even/dist/index.js/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.svg|.native.svg|.svg): /Users/user/project/eclipse-frontend/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js (289:17)

  287 |         }
  288 |         if (error instanceof InvalidPackageError) {
> 289 |           throw new PackageResolutionError({
      |                 ^
  290 |             packageError: error,
  291 |             originModulePath: from,
  292 |             targetModuleName: to,

ABI49_0_0RCTFatal
__37-[ABI49_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
0x0
```

This is my App.tsx from expo

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji */
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { isEven } from 'is-even';

export const App = () => {
  console.log(isEven(1));
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>hello</Text>
      {/* <Text>{isEven(1) ? 'yes' : 'no'}</Text> */}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the function from the package index.ts

```
    export const isEven = (x: number) => x % 2 === 0;
```

This is the package.json from the package

```
    {
       "name": "is-even",
       "version": "0.0.0",
       "main": "dist/index.js",
       "devDependencies": {},
       "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc index.ts --outDir dist"
      }
    }
```

I have already made sure that dist/index.js dose exist in the directory. and here is my directory structure:

```
-is-even (Folder)  
 ---dist (Folder)  
 ------index.js  
 ---index.ts  
 ---package.json
```

I have rebuild the dist already but it still dose not work, what could be the problem? And also in the same monorepo, I have another nextJS front end app which successfully called the same function from the same package.